# mySQL - how to flatten records and subrecords

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, that are something like this:

```
records
[id, submitted_date, username]

1,  2012-10-20, jjones
2,  2012-10-22, jsmith


subrecords
[id, record, name, value]

1,  1,  Street, 123 Elm
2,  1,  City,   Chicago
3,  2,  Street, 321 Maple
4,  2,  City,   New York
```

I am using a form tool that saves things this way.

In separate custom PHP, however, I want to get query results like:

```
jjones, 123 Elm, Chicago
jsmith, 321 Maple, New York
```

How do I do this?  The best I can figure out so far is output like

```
jjones, Street, 123 Elm
jjones, City, Chicago
jsmith, Street, 321 Maple
jsmith, City, New York
```

Which is not what I need. I want to get the results all together in the data rows returned from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join to subrecords twice, once for the street and once for the city:

```
select r.username, street.value, city.value
from records r
join subrecords street
  on street.record = r.id
   and street.name = 'Street'
join subrecords city
  on city.record = r.id
   and city.name = 'City'
order by r.username;
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. I fixed the typo, now r.id.

Answer (score 0):

I have no MySQL server in front of me to test it, but something like

```
select records.username, group_concat(subrecords.value separator ', ') as concatenated
from records join subrecords
on records.id = subrecords.record
group by records.username
```

I am not sure it works, as I have not tested. Let me know if there is any problem so I can edit the answer to make it more helpful.

Cheers.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, but is there a way to order the concatenated values? They seem to be in semi-random order, so the positions don't match for each record, e.g. row 1 - jjones, 123 Elm, Chicago row 2-
jsmith, New York, 321 Maple

Comment: You can achieve that by using the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do something like group_concat to put the "child results" into a single string, and with multiple columns it's likely to get ugly.. something like ~ or | separated columns and , separated records

something like

```
select a.id, group_concat(concat('~',b.id,b.name,b.value) seperator ',')
from a join b on b.record=a.id
group by a.id
```

I suppose you could break it up into different group_concats too like so:

```
select a.id, group_concat(b.id seperator ',')
group_concat(b.id seperator ',') ids
group_concat(b.name seperator ',') names
group_concat(b.value seperator ',') values
from a join b on b.record=a.id
group by a.id
```

whichever you find less painful to deal with on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As with previous answers, I can't test this yet. If group_concat causes issues derived tables might also work?

```
SELECT r.username, s1.value, s2.value
FROM
    records r
JOIN
    (SELECT value FROM subrecords WHERE name="Street") s1
ON
    (r.id = s1.record)
JOIN
    (SELECT value FROM subrecords WHERE name="City") s2
ON
    (r.id = s2.record)
```